# Moving from business to academia

Tags: phd

I've been working in commercial software development for quite a while for now, and I'm getting more and more disappointed in the way things are being done here as time passes.

So I was thinking to get back to academia, but the problem is that even though I hold master's degree, I have just a couple of publications (rather weak, I suppose), and there are no letters of recommendation in my disposal. Moreover, all colleagues I can possibly reference are engineers, not a scientists.

Basically, I'm quite used to applying to jobs I do not fit entirely (I mean not 100% of requirements met) judging by their requirements list in commercial sphere, but how mandatory publications and references are? My estimation is that I'm still capable of at least supporting research project as a engineer, while regaining lucking researcher skills.

Comment: What position are you hoping for?

Comment: Well, I guess "PhD student/junior researcher" should more or less precisely express my intents.

Comment: By _junior researcher_, what do you mean?

Comment: If you are disappointed by the way things are done in the commercial software environment, what do you expect to be different in the academic field? Attitude, procrastination, meetings and output....

Comment: Basically, I don't like software appliance. AI used to attach stickers to photo on the phone? Guess we can do better then that.

Comment: You can do it.  You don't really need publications.  You need to think through some things like income needs and status change (students are lower status in society than working professionals).  That said, it can be a very nice experience to be able to spend all of your time on some problem and know it best in the world.  You have a lot of time freedom also.  I  would not assume you will be having an impact on people/industry though (closer to that now).  But if you are of a theoretical bent, maybe it is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You question whether you satisfy the requirements for a position as a PhD student**. The minimum requirement for such a position is a bachelor's degree, albeit, many positions will require a master's. You satisfy both of those requirements, so your move from software development to academia is entirely plausible.

**You seem to believe that publications are required for a PhD student position**. They are not, at least, not at many institutes. They are nonetheless useful, even "just a couple," even if "[they're] rather weak," since they demonstrate an ability to do research and an understanding of the research process.

**You are concerned that your referees are engineers, rather than scientists**. This isn't a problem, actually it is an asset, as is your software engineering background. *Impact* is a measure of success in academia and your real-world experience can guide you towards practical research problems that have more potential for impact.

Answer (score 1):

You can go back as a PhD student and @user2768 has given a good answer to that. I just want to point out a different path.

Many research projects require software development. If you want to do research and not specifically computer science / engineering research, you could join a research group as their software developer. If you wanted to make a career out of it, you would probably need to get a PhD, but it may be that the research group would be able to help with that. In addition, it would allow you to see whether research is what you want to do while still being gainfully employed (albeit at a lower payscale than what you would get in commercial software development).